# How to execute more than 3 parallel http requests using RxJava (+ retrofit2) on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2, reactivex

I'm trying to learn how to work with RxJava (`io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1`) + retrofit2 + kotlin.

How Observable is involved in this, in general, figured out, even learned how to combine the results of 2-3 parallel queries based on the performance of all with the help of `Observable.zip`, BUT how to perform similarly more than 3 parallel queries I can not understand.

The source code for the Observable class has a method

```
static <T1, T2, T3, T4, R> Observable <R> zip (),
```

but it does not work like

```
static <T1, T2, T3, R> Observable <R> zip ()
```

in the case of three Observable inputs and `Function3 <*, *, *, *>.`

I tried already to make the first three queries using `zip`, then `flatMap` and so on, but it still does not work. Reading documentation and examples does not help to turn to the right direction. I looked towards `Observable.combineLatest`, but came to the conclusion (it may be erroneous) that the method would return the result of the first Observable that was executed.

What I want:

I have 4 methods that return Observable:

- this.orderRepository.getStatuses (): Observable
- this.orderRepository.getOrders (): Observable
- this.userRepository.getUsers (): Observable
- this.orderRepository.getTypes (): Observable

**Prompt, please, how should I compose these methods so that they run in parallel, and at the end get the result of all 4 methods in one place?**

It's already messed up, but I generally do not understand what I should do with the 4 Observables, so that they all in one place and return to the UI. + already confused with flatMap, map and so on ...

Please excuse me for mistakes

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. For 4 sources you need Function4: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/test/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableZipTest.java#L1180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `zip`, probably the problem that you had is because `zip` will only emit when all observables have emitted.

If you need to receive the updates as soon as you get them, I think that your best bet is to map the answers to a common type, for example:

```
class Response(val statuses: Statuses? = null, val orders: Orders? = null, val users: Users? = null, val types: Types? = null)

this.orderRepository.getStatuses().map(Response(statuses = it))
```

After you do this to all observables, you will be able to use `concat` or `merge` who will emit as soon as any observable emit.

More info:

http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1bddcd2